# Zariski's main theorem without inverse limits

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider the statement

> A proper birational map of varieties with a normal target has connected fibers.

Is there a proof of it that does not involve inverse limits at all?

Comment: This question is cold now but I would suggest that Zariski's original proof might not have involved inverse limits (I don't know anymore where to find it though...).